# Call class A method from within class B in class A's object property

Tags: javascript, oop

Given class A instance with a property object which contains class B instance, can I call A's method from within B?

For example this class represents a cart:

```
class jsCart {
  constructor() {
    this.products = {};
  }

  addProduct(product){
    this.products[product.id] = product;
  }

  removeProduct(id) {
    delete this.products[id];
  }
}
```

And this class represents a product:

```
class jsProduct {
  constructor(id, price, quantity) {
    this.id = id;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }

  set _quantity(n) {
    this.quantity = n;
  }
}
```

After adding an instance of jsProduct in jsCart as such:

```
let cart = new jsCart;
cart.addProduct(new jsProduct('bananas', 23, 1));
```

Can I call cart.removeProduct() from within the 'bananas' instance of jsProduct without knowing in advance the jsCart instance's var name ?

In other words, is there any way to generally refer to a containing jsCart instance from within jsProduct 'bananas' instance?

Thank you

Comment: No, there is not. There might be multiple carts containing your product object!

Comment: That does make sense ! do you want to add your comment as an answer ?

Comment: You can pass product a reference of container cart.

Comment: @Xaqron you mean on product creation ? Would that be good practice? As the main use-case for this question was for a product to self-remove from cart when quantity is 0 or less, an alternative I can think of would be to always update products through a method in jsCart, so I can check for 0, update, remove. Which one would you advice for ?

Comment: I'd prefer the latter approach (cart in control) but something in OO design seems wrong. Information/control flow usually is top/container to down/part (cart to product) but that is not a strict rule. My guess is you have background with monolithic application development.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.